# How to modify JSON property values at any depth with regex?

Tags: json, jq

I've received a collection of JSON schema files I must use to validate some data in JSON.
The values of the `$ref` properties in the schema are incomplete.  The validator tool is unable to resolve the references.  When I manually edit the `$ref` values in some schema files, I can get the validation to partially work.  However, the collection of JSON schema files is huge and I can't edit all of them manually, so I thought I could use jq to fix them.

An example of a schema with incomplete `$ref` values…

```
{
  "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "FubarAgent",
  "metaFormat": "http://example.org/fubar/",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "extensions": {
      "$ref": "TypeDefinitions#/extensions"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 2048,
      "title": "name"
    },
    "membership": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "Membership"
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 2048
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "title": "FubarAgent"
}
```

The problem is that each schema file is named `*object_name*.json`.  When the validator tries to resolve references in files named `TypeDefinitions` and `Membership` it fails, because the files are actually named `TypeDefinitions.json` and `Membership.json`.  The references above should be `TypeDefinitions.json#/extensions` and `Membership.json`, respectively.  (So, not simply appending `.json`.)   I tried to come up with jq code to use a regex to edit these references at any depth, but I haven't quite figured it out.

I came close in an earlier attempt, but it didn't work at all depths or use a regex.  The current version I have uses regex and works on some files, but not all.  It is…

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("$ref") then .["$ref"] = (. | sub("(?<a>[^#]*)(?<b>#.*)*$"; "\(.a).json\(.b + "")")) else . end)' FubarAgent.json
```

With the example schema from above, the output is…

```
jq: error (at FubarAgent.json:28): object ({"$ref":"Ty...) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

What should I do to fix it?  Also, it seems that what I have is very long.  Maybe there's a shorter way to do this that someone could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just update (`|=`) every `."$ref"` key that points to a string by prepending either the first `#` or the end of the string with `.json`?

```bash
(.. | objects."$ref" | strings) |= sub("(?<a>#|$)"; ".json\(.a)")
```

```json
{
  "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "FubarAgent",
  "metaFormat": "http://example.org/fubar/",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "extensions": {
      "$ref": "TypeDefinitions.json#/extensions"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 2048,
      "title": "name"
    },
    "membership": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "Membership.json"
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 2048
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "title": "FubarAgent"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SwKq88YF_3f)

---

###### Note explaining the version conflict:

jq version 1.7 fixed a bug with empty regex matches (see the [release info](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7): "Fix empty regular expression matches. @itchyny [#2677](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/2677)"). Prior to this version, the group matching on `$` would provide no corresponding field in the result object at all (while v1.7 produces `{"a": ""}`), so the string interpolation of `.a` would evaluate to `null`, producing the literal string `"null"`, which for this example eventually leads to the undesired result of `"$ref": "Membership.jsonnull"`.

For versions 1.5+ (since regexp support was added), this can be mitigated by explicitly treating that case: Add `// ""` to manually provide the empty string as an alternative if `.a` evaluates to a *falsy* value (like `null`).

```bash
(.. | objects."$ref" | strings) |= sub("(?<a>#|$)"; ".json\(.a // "")")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, that works great.  Apparently, not only did I have trouble wrapping my head around jq syntax, I wasn't grokking regex, either.  Your solution didn't work for me at first, but I realized it was because I had jq-1.6.  I upgraded to jq-1.7 and then it worked.  I also wanted to use this within Google Colab, but `apt install jq` there keeps getting me jq-1.6.

Comment: I worked around `apt install jq` on Google Colab giving me jq-1.6 by downloading the jq-1.7 binary from the app's releases on GitHub instead.

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan jq version 1.7 fixed a bug with empty-string regex matches. Prior versions simply ignored capturing them (like when matching on just `$`), which eventually caused the string interpolation to produce `null` in these cases (and `"$ref": "Membership.jsonnull"` in the example given). As a workaround for older versions, manually provide the empty string as an alternative, as described in my edited post.